# I am getting an error Kafka Connect HDFS connector and no data is written to HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

The Kafka connector is starting up OK and reads the data stream in the topic, however, it doesn't write any data and when I stop the connector i get an error

I have ensured the topic and logs directory is created on the HDFS filesystem

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=rstest
#hdfs.url=adl:///
hdfs.url=hdfs://headnodehost
flush.size=3
```

Here is the output from the screen

[2019-05-08 12:08:20,963] INFO Opening record writer for:       hdfs://headnodehost/topics//+tmp/rstest/partition=1/4ef1de96-bd7c-437c-b210-2ef6e62d3ead_tmp.avro (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider:66)
   ^C[2019-05-08 12:08:32,911] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,913] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:211)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,918] INFO Stopped http_8083@6c03fb16{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:306)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,958] INFO Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4e31c3ec{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:865)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,960] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:222)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,960] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:77)
   [2019-05-08 12:08:32,960] INFO Stopping task hdfs-sink-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:478)
   **[2019-05-08 12:08:33,113] ERROR Error discarding temp file hdfs://headnodehost/topics//+tmp/rstest/partition=1/4ef1de96-bd7c-437c-b210-2ef6e62d3ead_tmp.avro for rstest-1 partition=1 when closing TopicPartitionWriter: (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:451)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException:**   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at   io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider$1.close(AvroRecordWriterProvider.java:97)

Comment: What are the permissions of the HDFS directory you are trying to write to?

Comment: Fixed, issue was there was not enough data being streamed so it never got to commit point

Comment: You set `flush.size=3`, so you didn't have at least 3 messages?